# block non-specialized template c++

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Is it possible to somehow forbid using templated function for types for which specialization was not explicitly written. I mean something like that

```
template <typename T>
void foo(){}

template <>
void foo<int>(){}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    foo<int>(); //ok
    foo<char>(); //Wrong - no specialized version for char.
}
```

I cannot skip generic version of function, cause then compiler says, that foo is not a template function when i try to specialize. I could simply write something that does not compile in generic function, and add some comment explaining why, but this would be quite non-informative. What i would like to do, is to be able to directly cause compiler to go with error like "foo() is not defined".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure:  just don't define it and you'll get a linker error if you try to use it:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(); // not defined

template <>
void foo<int>() { }
```

Alternatively, you can use some variation of a static assert to give a "nicer" compile-time error.  Here is an example using the C++0x `static_assert`.  Note that you must make the `false` value dependent upon the template parameter, otherwise the `static_assert` may be triggered when the template is parsed.

```
template <typename T>
struct dependent_false { enum { value = false }; };

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "Oops, you used the primary template");
}
```

Note that it's usually best [not to specialize function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).  Instead, it is better to delegate to a specialized class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl
{
    static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "Oops, you used the primary template");
};

template<>
struct foo_impl<int>
{
    static void foo() { }
};

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    return foo_impl<T>::foo();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just don't supply definition for the default generic template.